# What is best way to use instance of one class into another class without passing into constructor

Tags: java, gwt, design-patterns

**If both classes are at same level (Both are child class), how to use instance of one class into another one.What is best way to use instance of one class into another class without passing into constructor?** so manually require to pass null. How to make independent code?

```
    Class PreviewPanel{

    private PreviewPanel(Builder builder) {
        this.previewMode=builder.previewMode;

        formsPreview=new NTFormsPreview(previewMode);
        formsPreview.setCanAddComment(builder.canAddComment);

        ntPreviewTreePanel=new NTPreviewTreePanel(builder,formsPreview);
    //This class have some event bus implemented.Sometime There, formsPreview instance is require.

           }
    public static class Builder {
        private PreviewMode previewMode;

        private Document document;
        public Builder(PreviewMode previewMode,Document document) {
            this.previewMode = previewMode;
            this.document=document;
        }
        public PreviewPanel build() {
              return new PreviewPanel(this);
        }

     }
}
```

If I pass that instance into constructor,**I have to follow chain of inner class and pass same instance to reach specific class**. I want to avoid it. This is big product. it is not easy to show how many classes inside it to reach actual handler implementation.

### **Code Structure:**

```
private PreviewPanel(Builder builder)
    ->formsPreview=new NTFormsPreview(previewMode);

        ->NTPreviewTreePanel(builder,formsPreview);
                 ->NTPreviewTree(document, bidDocuments, previewMode, canAddComment,canViewComment, previewFormTxnEncryptionDetails,formsPreview);
             ->NTTreeNode(formsPreview)
                private void fireReportItemClicked(Document document,esenderCSReport){
                                eventBus.fireEventFromSource(formPreviewEvent, formsPreview);   
                }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What instance do you want to inject, and where?  The sentence _"As sometime NTPreviewTreePanel is not required NTFormsPreview instance"_ is ambiguous at best.  Can you clarify with explicit examples?

Comment: is there any way to use instance of one class into another class without passing instance into constructor?

Comment: Could you just have a public property of the class you want to use on the class that you set? Another option is using an IoC container like Unity.

Comment: @JimGarrison This is related to gwt event bus queries. I have used "eventBus.addHandler(type, handler)" handler. But it fires unrequired event like if three instance create for same class. If I fire event for one class, it fires for all three class. I found solution "eventBus.addHandlerToSource" to pass instance (resource) also. so it will fire instance specific. but it's not always same case.

Comment: Why not a simple demonstration of the query? Why so extra material posted with the question that is not relevant to the query? -1 for this reason. Please edit the question with only the relevant details, needed for the query. `public class A extends C` will suffice, then why making the example so complicated with `public class NTFormsPreview extends ScrollPanel` and then overriding methods for no reason :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw I have already ask question 
"is there any way to use instance of one class into another class without passing instance into constructor?" no replied so try to put code. If I pass that instance into constructor, **I have to follow chain of inner class and pass same instance to reach specific class. I want to avoid it.** This is big product. it is not easy to show how many classes inside it to reach actual handler implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to use instance of one class into another class without passing instance into constructor?

There are other ways.

- Pass the instance of the second class to the first class using a `setter` method.
- Pass the instance of the second class to the first class by assigning to a instance variable in the first class.
- Create the instance of the second class in the first class.

If you an answer that is more relevant to your example, you will need to explain more clearly what you are trying to do here, and why you think that your current solution is unsatisfactory.

---

Re this attempted explanation:

> I have to follow chain of inner class and pass same instance to reach specific class. I want to avoid it.

I have no idea what you are trying to say.  I suspect that other readers has the same problem.

I suspect that the real problem here is with the design of your existing code.  It looks like you / someone has gone a bit crazy with nesting classes, and that you are suffering the consequences.  It could be that the only way to simplify things is to unpick the nesting or rethink the constructors.  (Why does a *private* constructor require a "builder" argument?)

---

It is a fairly common phenomenon for complicated OO software to have inherently complicated initialization patterns.  There tends to be no neat way to deal with this programatically, but you can often avoid this by using some kind of "Dependency Injection" (DI) mechanism.  Another name for this is "Inversion of Control" (IoC).

For example, Spring DI works by adding annotations to your class, and getting Spring to create and assemble the instances in the required form.  Or you can specify how the instances (beans) are assembled in XML.

This could be a solution for you ...

Comment: Thanks, I have try to put structure related to it. When I pass instance into this class, I have to go through no of class and methods. so I don't know that it's good or bad!!

Comment: @TBM - I don't think we can help you further.  The solution (if there is one) is likely to be specific to your problem, and your problem seems to be too complicated to describe.

Comment: Why does a private constructor require a "builder" argument? because builder class has this method. `public PreviewPanel build() {return new PreviewPanel(this);}`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is unclear to me but I think you could do the following :

Create a new Class that will "Own both of your child class - composition"

Make it work a Mediator Pattern so that one can use and call stuff on the other one following the rule/logic you want.

1. No need to pass one of the child to the other one in any way.
2. Freely, redesign the interaction logic if it gets to change
3. No need to "change"" the structure you already have

FYI The builder, seems to be related to the Builder Pattern, you might wanna read on it and see if you can understand something out of your project.

Comment: thanks for "Mediator Pattern" suggestion. let me check.